# Is it possible to use SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

Is it possible to use `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` clause together?
I need `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate values and make a single entry of the records, and then get the Total quantity of those duplicate values.

*For example*, I have columns like *Item Name* and *Quantity* and their records are **(product A,5)**, **(product A,7)**.

Since products are the same I want it as a single entry and then total its quantity. So, the output on my report would be like this: **(product A,12)**

Can `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` clause solve this together?

Comment: You can nest queries with each nesting level having their own DISTINCT and GROUP BY. The example in your question could be solved simply with `select Name, sum(Quantity) as 'Total' from Product group by Name`, it's not clear why you'd want DISTINCT there. Can you expand your example?

Comment: thank you for responding. because i want a summarized records on my crystal reports that's why i'm using DISTINCT. i don't want a repetitive records on my report since they are the same product name

Comment: and then add their qty to make it a summarized report

Comment: `GROUP BY` will result in distinct rows, it does this automatically, you do NOT need distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment on Used_By_Already's answer, I think you need to use sum() over (...) construct, such as the following...

```sql
create table [dbo].[Purchases_Supplier] (
  [Purchased From] nvarchar(50),
  Address nvarchar(50),
  [Transaction Month] nvarchar(6),
  Category nvarchar(50),
  Articles nvarchar(50),
  Unit int,
  [Unit Price] money,
  Qty int,
  Tin nvarchar(50),
  Cashier nvarchar(50)
);

insert [dbo].[Purchases_Supplier] values
  ('Acme', '123 Street', '202003', 'Baubles', 'Product A', 1, 1.1, 5, 'Nickel', 'John'),
  ('Acme', '123 Street', '202003', 'Baubles', 'Product A', 1, 1.1, 7, 'Nickel', 'John'),
  ('Acme', '123 Street', '202003', 'Baubles', 'Product B', 1, 1.1, 9, 'Silver', 'Maria'),
  ('Acme', '123 Street', '202003', 'Baubles', 'Product B', 1, 1.1, 11, 'Silver', 'Maria');

declare @Supplier_Name nvarchar(50) = N'Acme',
  @Month_Purc nvarchar(6) = '202003',
  @Cat nvarchar(50) = 'Baubles';

select
  Articles,
  Qty,
  Unit,
  [Unit Price],
  [Purchased From],
  Address,
  Tin,
  Cashier,
  -- NOTE: partition by has everything in the GROUP BY except [Qty]...
  sum(Qty) over (partition by Articles, Unit, [Unit Price], [Purchased From], Address, Tin, Cashier) as Total
from dbo.Purchases_Supplier
where [Purchased From] = @Supplier_Name
and [Transaction Month] = @Month_Purc
and Category = @Cat
group by Articles, Qty, Unit, [Unit Price], [Purchased From], Address, Tin, Cashier;
```

Which yields the result:

```
Articles  Qty  Unit  Unit Price  Purchased From  Address     Tin    Cashier  Total
Product A   5     1      1.1000  Acme            123 Street  Nickel John        12
Product A   7     1      1.1000  Acme            123 Street  Nickel John        12
Product B   9     1      1.1000  Acme            123 Street  Silver Maria       20
Product B  11     1      1.1000  Acme            123 Street  Silver Maria       20
```

Comment: based from your example, i want it to be like two rows only Product A and Product B

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` will result in distinct rows, it does this automatically, you do NOT also need `SELECT DISTINCT` to reduce the number of rows.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    product  VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
>   ,quantity INTEGER  NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(product,quantity) VALUES ('a',7);
> INSERT INTO mytable(product,quantity) VALUES ('a',5);
> INSERT INTO mytable(product,quantity) VALUES ('b',17);
> INSERT INTO mytable(product,quantity) VALUES ('b',15);
> ```
>
> ```
> select product, sum(quantity) as qty
> from mytable
> group by product
> ```
>
> product | qty
> :------ | --:
> a       |  12
> b       |  32

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd203a91f6c504ecc358fc3a079b679f)*
Note that there is a single row in that result, i.e. only one row for each distinct value in the column called `product` because we specified that column in the `GROUP BY` clause.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b33921748003e0a838705bd22fceef84)*

Comment: SELECT ARTICLES,UNIT,[UNIT PRICE],SUM(QTY) * [UNIT PRICE] AS TOT_AMOUNT,[PURCHASED FROM],[ADDRESS],TIN,CASHIER,
SUM(QTY) as TOTAL FROM PURCHASES_SUPPLIER WHERE [PURCHASED FROM]=@supplier_name AND [TRANSACTION MONTH]=@month_purc AND CATEGORY=@cat

GROUP BY 
   ARTICLES,QTY,UNIT,[UNIT PRICE],AMOUNT,[PURCHASED FROM],[ADDRESS],TIN,CASHIER

Comment: here's my query, is that possible?